# How do I redirect to a mobile site but keep the hash tag?

Tags: mobile, redirect, safari, location, hashtag

I'm looking to have it so that when a user loads our page it checks to see if they're on a mobile device and then it'll redirect them to a mobile version of our site, but keep the original hash tag from the link they followed. I've tried setting the new location with the hash tag in javascript and it works in Chrome but doesn't work in Safari. I've read that this is just something Safari does. Is there any work around to this?

Comment: Yeah, I was just setting the Window.location in javascript. Turns out Safari doesn't support hash tag redirects, which is very annoying considering that iPhones and iPads are all Safari. So some js like this window.location = "http://www.example.com/#page2" would take you to the site, but it won't jump to page2 like the hash tag says. Safari strips the hash tag when redirecting.

Comment: Where did you read *this is just something Safari does*?

Answer (score 4):

We actually just got a very similar bug report from our customers.

For us the scenario involved a hashtag in the form of `#quicklogin/abc123` and only appeared when viewing the site in Safari. This was part of the initial URL that the client would load and it would present them with an alternate login screen. When going directly to the URL in Safari, the browser removed the entire tag and ignored it.

When we changed this to something like `#quicklogin/test` (or any other hash containing only alpha characters) it worked fine. It also worked fine when loading the site and then manually applying the hash tag in two separate steps.

So our conclusion is that there may be something wrong with hashtags containing numeric values in Safari.

Comment: We tested this a bit, and *only* lowercase letters work (`a-z`). At least `=`, `_` and `Z` resulted in Safari removing the entire fragment.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do this either by redirecting with javascript (because javascript can read the hash value) or by conditionally returning different html based on the user agent.

Browsers are supposed to preserve the hash fragment through a 302, but often don't (see 3 year old webkit bug below) and otherwise hash fragments are not sent to the server so they can't be dealt with manually.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24175

Answer (score 4):

You should escape '#' symbol and everything would be OK

Comment: This makes no more sense than the other copy of it you posted on another question.

Comment: This actually works... Substituting the "#" with "%23" works like a charm!  Thank-you!